# Regex to extract amounts from Outlook email body

Tags: excel, regex, vba, outlook

I have an email that comes into a shared folder every day, and I'm trying to extract specific values out of the email. There's some text, and then two dollar amounts that I need to pull out.

Here's the email, with what I need highlighted in Group1 https://regex101.com/r/5YOJnG/20

I have been able to select the folder, and was able to pull the body of the email I want out. Actually pulling the specific number out of the body of the email has been a challenge, though. I've gotten regex101 to get Group 1 to match my desired output, but haven't been able to translate that into successful code.

Here is my code - MyAr (24) and MyAr(32) print the correct numbers - 10,706,855.69 and (10,365,481.96) - but the regex returns 70 at the moment.

```
Option Explicit

Sub OutlookTesting()

Dim y As Workbook
Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olfldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim sharedemail As Outlook.Recipient
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim myTasks As Outlook.Items
Dim MyAr() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim regEx As Object
Dim tester As Variant
Dim Pattern1 As String

Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Sam.Givens\OneDrive - Motiva Enterprises LLC\Desktop\VBA Forecast.xlsm")
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set sharedemail = olNS.CreateRecipient("MOTIVA-Forecasting@motiva.com")
Set olfldr = olNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedemail, olFolderInbox)
Set folder = olfldr
Set myTasks = folder.Items

myTasks.Sort "Subject"

i = 1

For Each olMail In myTasks
    If InStr(olMail.Subject, "Retail Cash Forecast 09/30/2020") > 0 Then
        MyAr = Split(olMail.Body, vbCrLf)
        Debug.Print (MyAr(24))
        Debug.Print (MyAr(32))
        Pattern1 = "^[0-9.,()]*$"
        Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
            With regEx
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .pattern = Pattern1
                Set tester = .Execute(i)
            End With
        Next i
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next olMail

Debug.Print (tester(0))

Set olfldr = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Edit with working code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub OutlookTesting()

Dim y As Workbook
Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olfldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim sharedemail As Outlook.Recipient
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim myTasks As Outlook.Items
Dim regEx As Object
Dim Matches As Variant
Dim Matches2 As Variant
Dim Pattern1 As String
Dim Pattern2 As String
Dim BodyText

Set y = Workbooks.Open("<Excel File Location>")
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set sharedemail = olNS.CreateRecipient("<Mailbox Recipient>")
Set olfldr = olNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedemail, olFolderInbox)
Set folder = olfldr
Set myTasks = folder.Items

myTasks.Sort "Subject"

For Each olMail In myTasks
    If InStr(olMail.Subject, "<Subject>") > 0 Then
        BodyText = olMail.Body
        Pattern1 = "\bCredit\s*\d*\s+\(([0-9,.]*)"
        Pattern2 = "\bDebit\s*\d*\s+([0-9,.]*)"
        Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .pattern = Pattern1
            If .Test(BodyText) Then
                Set Matches = .Execute(BodyText)
            End If
        End With
        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .pattern = Pattern2
            If .Test(BodyText) Then
                Set Matches2 = .Execute(BodyText)
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next olMail
Debug.Print (Matches(0).submatches(0))
Debug.Print (Matches2(0).submatches(0))

Set olfldr = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I think part of your issue is trying to use `i` in both of those areas. When it's used during the loop it'll end up being reset to the upper bound of the array so your incrementing would be nullified

Comment: Thanks for responding - if I add in `Dim m As Long` and change to `For m = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)` and `Next m`, leaving the `i =1` and `i = i + 1` static, I still have the same issue of "no match". Is that what you meant for me to change, or am I misunderstanding your suggestion? Fairly new to vba, so not super sure that's what you were saying.

Comment: all you need is Group 1 ?

Comment: Set up your regex object before you enter the loop, else you will be setting up multiple regex objects unnneccessarily.  And to return the group 1, something like:  `debug.print tester(0).submatches(0)`

Comment: Yes, all I need is Group 1, 0m3r. Ron, I tried using your suggestions. I moved `Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")` through `End With` just below `MyAr = Split(olMail.Body, vbCrLf)`, is that what you meant? And when I run that with `debug.print tester(0).submatches(0)`, I get a type mismatch on the debug.print line.

Comment: (1) You are searching the text body.  Is there an Html body?  It might hold this data in a table with the amounts in column 3 and the currencies in column 4.  Extracting from such a table could be easier than trying to split the text lines.  (2) In your regex expression you search for "Debit " but the second line contains "Credit".

Comment: Hey Tony. The email contains both Credit and Debit, and I'm looking to get both. My idea was to figure out how to get the Debit side and then move on to the Credit version, since the logic would be by and large the same. I would ultimately have two regex functions to pull both numbers out.

I'm not sure if there is an HTML body - how would I find that out in this case, and how would I then search that instead?

Comment: This question belongs to you so you are automatically told about any comments added by other people.  If you reply to one of those comments, type @ followed by the author's name so they are told about your reply.

Comment: I never work on an email without first using my diagnostic routine for emails to output the important properties.  I have posted a copy as https://stackoverflow.com/a/58000707/973283.  I assume the image you have posted is from a screen shot.  The display image is not always a good indicator of what a VBA macro will see.  This could be part of your problem.

Comment: An Outlook email has up to three bodies: text, Html and RTF (Rich text format).  I have never seen a RTF body although there is the occasional question about them.  Ignoring RTF, an email can have a text body (property Body) an Html body (property HtmlBody) or both.  If there is an Html body, that is what the user sees.  A macro can see either.  If there is a table, it can be simple with just the tags and no formatting.  Alternatively, it can have lots of formatting and classes.

Comment: If the Html body just has the tags, it is easy to count tags to the required column.  If  the Html table uses classes to identify the columns, VBA has functions to extract values by class.  Until you have seen the bodies as they appear to a macro, you cannot know how best to proceed.  My diagnostic routine formats the bodies in a way that would allow you to post the important parts within your question.  Use the {} option at the top of the edit window to format the bodies so they display nicely.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld

Just leaned about this function, sorry - please see earlier comment

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Just leaned about this function, sorry - please see earlier comment

Comment: @0m3r Just leaned about this function, sorry - please see earlier comment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54316610/4539709

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41753613/4539709

Comment: @TonyDallimore thank you for the suggestions! I'll try these out tomorrow morning and get back to you!

Comment: @0m3r I edited my code above trying to follow the general format of your link, and it feels like maybe my regex pattern is just off? The code I have currently returns 10,706,855.69 and (10,365,481.96) as the results MyAr(24) and MyAr(32), but my regEx function returns 70, and I have no idea from where it's getting that. I also tried your function to print multiple matches, but it keeps giving an error that is giving me the impression that there's only one match, and it's that 70. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand why you are executing the regexp on the loop index in your code here `Set tester = .Execute(i)`. Shouldn't that be `Set tester = .Execute(MyAr(i))`?  And then you're not checking for a match immediately following the .execute, but continuing with the loop? What am I missing? What is your UBound on MyAr? 70 perhaps?

Comment: @user9601310 If I `Set tester = .Execute(MyAr(i))`, then I get an error of Invalid procedure call or argument on `Debut.Print (tester(0))`. For the latter question, should I move the debut.print (tester) into the regex function? And something like that - not sure exactly what the upper bound is, how would I check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your approach is perhaps a little off target.  I've looked at your example at regex101.com and come up with an alternate section of code as below.  This is VBScript but apart from the "Set re ..." line as noted, it should run unchanged in VBA. I'm sure you can adapt it to suit your context :-).

As far as I can determine, you don't need to split the message text into separate lines and use a loop as you are doing (and yes, your `Debug.Print` is in the wrong place!). Both the debit and credit amounts can be captured in a single regex test, but because the match is across different lines, it needs the [\s\S]* included in the pattern. (Note that the "Multiline" setting somewhat counterintuitively is irrelevant for this).

```
Dim BodyText
Dim Pat
Dim re
Dim Matches
Pat = "\bDebit\s*\d*\s+([0-9,.]*)\sUSD[\s\S]*Credit\s\d+\s\(([0-9,.]*)\)\sUSD"
'-- Pat1 = "\bCredit\s*\d*\s+\(([0-9,.]*)\)"
'-- Pat2 = "\bDebit\s*\d*\s+([0-9,.]*)"

           'vvvvvvv Assign your olMail.Body to BodyText here
BodyText = "Hello," & vbCrLf  & vbCrLf & _
    "Please release. " & vbCrLf & _ 
    "Please find below the retail cash forecast that will be drafted xx/xx/xxxx."  & vbCrLf  & _
    " RUN ID    No. Amount                          Curr." & vbCrLf & _
    "xxxxx - Direct Debit   13  10,706,855.69   USD" & vbCrLf & _
    "xxxxx - Direct Credit  213122  (10,365,481.96) USD"  & vbCrLf & _
    "TOTAL      341,373.73  USD"
Set re = New RegExp  '-- For VBA use Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With re
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = Pat
    If .Test(BodyText) Then
        Set Matches = .Execute(BodyText)
        MsgBox "Debit = " & Matches.item(0).submatches(0) & vbCrLf & "Credit = " & Matches.item(0).submatches(1), ,"Result"
    Else
        MsgBox "No match", ,"Result"
    End If
End With
```

[image: Result]

Just as an additional note, there are a couple of additional items in the pattern that you may need to adjust. As you may see, it currently checks for USD after the debit and credit amounts.  It also checks for brackets i.e. "()" surrounding the credit amount. If these are not relevant, just remove them.

Comment: you beauty. Made a couple small changes to this - the combined pattern didn't work for mine for whatever reason - I kept getting an error, so I'll just run two regex's in mine with each pattern - but this worked like a charm. My day is indescribably better. Thank you so much!

Comment: @givenss93 Thank you!  Will you be marking the answer as accepted?

Comment: yep - sorry! @user9601310 New to stackoverflow and didn't know that was a thing. Just did!